# "If x is a difference of squares, prove that 3x is a difference of squares as well."

Tags: square-numbers

I'm banging my head against the wall with this task:

> Prove that if $x$ is a difference of integer squares, then $3x$ is a difference of integer squares as well.

What strategies could I utilise in order to prove this?

Comment: When is an odd number a difference of squares?  What about an even number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $x=u^2-v^2$ with $u,v\in \Bbb Z$, then $3x=3(u^2-v^2)=3(u+v)(u-v)=(3u+3v)(u-v)=((2u+v)+(u+2v))((2u+v)-(u+2v))=(2u+v)^2-(u+2v)^2$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I wouldn't have thought of this.

Comment: +1 elegance....

Answer (score 0):

A little late here but one can generalize the problem as follows:

*Claim.* If $M,x$ are two integers that can be written as difference of squares of two integers, then $Mx$ is also a difference of squares of two integers. Note that in the original post $M=3=2^2-1^2.$

*Proof of claim.* Write $M=p^2-q^2,$ and $x=u^2-v^2$, for suitable $u,v,p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $Mx=(p^2-q^2)(u^2-v^2)=p^2u^2-p^2v^2-q^2u^2+q^2v^2=(pu+qv)^2-(qu+pv)^2.$